# Downgrade Heroku Postgres from standard to hobby

Tags: heroku

[image]I'm trying to downgrade a heroku postgres db from standard to hobby basic. As I'm not fully using the web app currently but there is still some data in there that needs to be kept.  How can I downgrade? (some downtime is fine).

Update: managed to setup and promote a new database based on the inststructions below, but i can't deprovision the old one.
`heroku info` shows:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku's instructions for [upgrading with pg:copy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrading-with-pg-copy) will also work for downgrading. Here's the summary:

1. Provision a new database
2. Enter maintenance mode to prevent database writes
3. Transfer data to the new database
4. Promote the new database
5. Exit maintenance mode

If your app isn't live (not being actively written to), you can skip the maintenance mode steps.

Once you've done that, you can [deprovision your old database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#deprovisioning-the-old-primary-database).

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. I couldn't deprovision my old database though.  How do I determnine what the old database is called to deprovision.  When I use `heroku info` it doesn't list the database url. (pic stuck above).

Comment: `heroku pg:info` will display detailed info about each database provisioned for your app.